# Unable to install biobert

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install biobert

When I run the command cd biobert; pip install -r requirements.txt, I get the following error

```
Preeti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.obj -D_GNU_SOURCE
    objToJSON.c
    c:\users\drpreeti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c(193): error C2065: 'NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL': undeclared identifier
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c(193): warning C4047: 'return': 'void *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c(429): warning C4090: 'initializing': different 'const' qualifiers
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c(459): warning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c(663): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'int', possible loss of data
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c(951): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c(1042): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'int', possible loss of data
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c(1862): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_float64' to 'npy_int64', possible loss of data
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\drpreeti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\drpreeti\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dhpu3wu9\\pandas\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\drpreeti\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dhpu3wu9\\pandas\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\drpreeti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rwimvitd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\drpreeti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pandas' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\drpreeti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be caused by a missing or outdated version of *NumPy*, a *Pandas* dependency.

```
pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c(193): error C2065: 'NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL': undeclared identifier
```

Install/update numpy to the latest version before re-running the biobert installation.

```
pip install numpy -U
```